# Why Xamarin ClipboardManager does not contains html only plain text?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, clipboardmanager

I am trying to simulate Copy/Paste behavior of HTML text like Gmail does it. I.e. If I manually copy from Chrome page some text to the new mail in Gmail, the formatting of the text stays (more or less) with bullets, headers and etc.

I've tried use the Clipboard manager, but it contains only one Clip that has plain-text formatting. What do I do wrong?

```
    ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.ClipboardService);

    ClipDescription decr = clipboardManager.PrimaryClip.Description;
    clipboardManager.PrimaryClip;
```

Comment: If you cannot find it maybe you can raise the concern to GitHub: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android

Comment: Yes, probably I should

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `GetItemAt` method and choose if you wish to coerce it to the format that your app requires:

#### Example (assuming the first clip data is the one you want):

```
var htmlText = clipboardManager.PrimaryClip.GetItemAt(0).HtmlText;
var coercedHtmlText = clipboardManager.PrimaryClip.GetItemAt(0).CoerceToHtmlText;
var coercedFormattedStyledText = clipboardManager.PrimaryClip.GetItemAt(0).CoerceToStyledTextFormatted;
```

Comment: I've tried to get the HtmlText property and it is null, the last two are undefined

Comment: @Tanya Does changing `0` to another value (1, 2 etc) change the outcome?

Comment: Yes, it writes that there is no such an element. :-)